# Dojo or Cappuccino or Sproutcore in term of speed and memory usage?

Tags: dojo, sproutcore, cappuccino

I want to develop a web application, but I need a strong and recent speed&memory comparison between Dojo, Cappuccino and Sproutcore, preferably latest version;

Comment: To do a comparison you'd need identical things to compare, but these three frameworks all take different approaches to web development. I doubt such a comparison exists, or is objective enough to be 'strong' enough for you, whatever that means.

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

This is really hard to answer without more context about what you're trying to build. By their very nature Cappuccino and SC add a fairly large amount of boilerplate/complexity on page load. Great if you're building single page applications (think Gmail, with a ~10s page load, but you only do that once a session), useless if you're building Web 2.0 style web *sites* (think Facebook, new pageload every few mins), as page loads are cripplingly slow with Cappuccino and SC.

Which leads to another interesting question. What are you trying to optimize (do you even know yet?). Page load? Data latency? UI responsiveness?

For most front end apps the cost of retrieving data from the server is an order of magnitude greater bottleneck than the front end code anyway.

Comment: Thanks; Well, I actually want a UI responsiveness and relatively small memory footprint (not page load), and I want a comparison

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think such a comparison exists.

All three are written by very capable developers and capable of creating cutting edge webapps - see me.com (SproutCore), 280slides.com (Cappuccino) and AOL mails project Phoenix (Dojo) to name three off the top of my head.

Comment: You're probably better off reviewing which programming model best fits your problem domain/development experience and wishes and taking it from there. All three frameworks are undergoing heavy development, so even if there were a comparison it'll be out of date next month. And all three are open source, so when (if?) you start to hit the limits of the technology in your own application you can fix them up as needed yourself.

Comment: If performance really is critical to your operation I'd probably take Dojo. It's a leaner programming model (not having an MVC framework to auto-generate code) so you get finer control of what gets loaded. Disclaimer: I've got about 1,000,000 times more experience with Dojo than SC or Cap.